# Meaning of for in this poetry

Tags: meaning, grammar, ambiguity

The word *for* creates ambiguous ideas in my native language, so I really can't understand the main objective in this phrase:

"Why does she sing her sad songs for me, I'm not the one"

It is a verse of a Townes Van Zandt song.

So, my doubt is how this sentence is interpreted by English speakers:

A.She sings the sad songs because of him, just for him that she sings.
B.The songs are sad because of him.
C.She just sings directed to him, but not especially for him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a mix between your A and C options. She is directing her singing to him and specifically for him.

In English (or at least standard American English), singing for someone means you are singing to that person; you are directing your singing to that person.

Now taking the entire sentence into consideration, he is questioning her singing because, based on historical romantic traditions you see in novels and movies, it is a sign that she is interested in him, but he thinks they aren't compatible.

So the meaning of *for* here is simply one of direction. She is singing to him.